# Want Eclipse to use a specific config.ini, but set a different configuration area

Tags: eclipse, osgi

So my problem in short is this:

I want to run my eclipse based program with a specific config.ini file which is *not* in the default dir, i.e it is *not* in `../eclipse/configuration/config.ini` but at the same time I want the configuration area to be in a different location, the users home directory.

The reasons have to do with using several different config.ini files and the configuration area where the files are saved is readonly.

When starting up the tool with

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java 
-Dosgi.baseConfiguration.area=$INSTALLATION/$CONFIGURATION/eclipse/configuration\
-jar $INSTALLATION/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar \
```

and this in my config.ini (amongst other things):

```
 osgi.configuration.area=@user.home/tmp/eclipse_data/
```

I get almost everything I want: The right config.ini file is used, the tool starts to cache data to the right place and only there. But with the little downside that the tool doesnt start up... I get the error message:

`!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-11-29 19:17:06.914
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)`

If I change to

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -Dawt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit \
-Dosgi.configuration.area=$INSTALLATION/$CONFIGURATION/eclipse/configuration \
-jar $INSTALLATION/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar \
```

the tool works, but starts to save data into my writeprotected area.

It is not an issue with the bundle definition in my config.ini file, since they work in the second scenario.

There are several workarounds for this, but first I'm gonna try to see if there is a way to make this work like we want to first.

**Update:** Following Kanes suggestion below, I found that only one bundle was being loaded, `org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517`. When I examined the eclipse code in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.sonatype.tycho/org.eclipse.osgi/3.6.0.v20100517/org/eclipse/core/runtime/internal/adaptor/EclipseAppLauncher.java#EclipseAppLauncher) that throws the exception I found this line:

```
if (failOnNoDefault && runnable == null)
throw new IllegalStateException(EclipseAdaptorMsg.ECLIPSE_STARTUP_ERROR_NO_APPLICATION);
```

So my runnable is null. Not sure why, but I think it's a sign that I got to use some workaround.

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In first way, you have to add 'osgi.bundles' as your vm argument. The error message is caused by the bundles aren't installed into the OSGi framework that is responsibility of bundle 'org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator' since eclipse 3.4.

```
-Dosgi.bundles=file/<eclipsedir>/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar@1\:start
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry, perhaps I should have been more clear. The config.ini file contains more than the row listed, I have specified all the bundles in it.

Comment: @Fredrik, all right. You could try append arguments '-console -noExit' in your command line. Then use 'ss' to see whether other bundles are installed or not in the framework.

Comment: how to load the fragment using config.ini file.. same @1\:start ?